# Hall's Theorem of Solvable Groups (Conjugacy)

Tags: group-theory

The problem is asking for a proof of Hall's theorem for finite solvable groups, namely that there exist Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$ a finite solvable group for any set of primes $\pi$ and furthermore that they are all conjugate. I proved existence for all cases, was able to narrow down the potential exceptions of conjugacy to the case where $|G|=p^an$, where $n$ is the order of a Hall $\pi$-subgroup and $p^a$ is the only order possible of a minimal  nontrivial normal subgroup $M$. With $N/M$ a minimal normal $q$-subgroup of $G/M$, I can also prove that for $Q∈\text{Syl}_q(N)$, $n$ divides $N_G(Q)$ where $Q$ is assumed nonnormal in $G$ so that by induction all the Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $N_G(Q)$ are conjugate, but how to prove that an arbitrary Hall $\pi$-subgroup is contained in $N_G(Q)$?

Plainly put, I don't understand the justification behind the final sentence of the solution [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/in-a-finite-solvable-group-hall-subgroups-exist-and-are-conjugate/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $H$ be an arbitrary Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$. It is not necessarily true that $H \le N_G(Q)$, but $|H|=n$ and $H$ is a complement of $M$, so $|H \cap N| = |N/M| = |Q|$. So $H \cap N$ is  Sylow $q$-subgroup of $N$ and hence is conjugate to $Q$. That is, there exists $g \in N$ with $(H \cap N)^g = Q$. Now $H \le N_G(H \cap N)$, so $H^g \le N_G(Q)$ and so $H^g$ is a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $N_G(Q)$ and we are done.

Comment: Most likely I'm forgetting something evident about the normalizer subgroup of $Q$, but how is that final clause entailed?

Comment: I've added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma:
Let $M$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ of order prime power $p$. There is a normal subgroup $M^{\prime}$ of order prime power $p$ so $M\leq M^{\prime}\unlhd G$ and the minimal normal subgroup of $G/M^{\prime}$ has prime power $q\neq p$.

Proof of Lemma:
Suppose $G/M$ has a minimal normal subgroup $M^{\prime}/M$ of prime power $p$. Then $M^{\prime}$ is normal in $G$ of order prime power $p$ greater than $M$. $G$ is finite so the process must terminate when $M^{\prime}$ is the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Proof:
Let $\pi$ be any set of primes. The induction hypothesis is that all groups of order less than $n$ contain all Hall $\pi$-subgroups and Hall $\pi$-subgroups of the same order are conjugate. The base case can be $G=1$ but it suffices and is obvious to use all groups through order $29$ (all solvable by Theorem~6.1.11 and the non-trivial Hall $\pi$-subgroups are Sylow subgroups).

The first non-trivial case occurs for $\left|G\right|=30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ (solvable: by Example~4.5, Groups of order $30$: there is the chain $1\unlhd Z_{15}\unlhd G$) and serves as an unsophisticated example of the method ($Q$ will be normal in $G$). Again, by the example in \S 4.5, it is known that the subgroups of order $3$ and $5$ are normal in $G$ and the subgroup of order $2$ is not normal so the minimal normal subgroup $M$ has order $3$. Then the order of $G/M$ is $10$ so there are Sylow subgroups of order $2$ and $5$. That is, $G$ has Hall subgroups of order $6$ and $15$ (the existence of the latter is also established in the example of \S 4.5). Observe that $\pi$ for the Hall subgroup of order $10$ cannot contain $3$ so this is the case $p\not\in\pi$. The Sylow subgroups of $G$ all have prime power $1$ so there can be no reduction in order. That is, the minimal normal subgroup cannot be a proper non-trivial subgroup of a Sylow subgroup (it must be the Sylow subgroup). Then a minimal normal subgroup $N/M$ of $G/M$ has order $5$ so $N$ has a Sylow $5$-subgroup $Q$ normal in $G$. The order of $G/Q$ is $6$ so there are Sylow subgroups of order $2$ and $3$. That is, $G$ has Hall subgroups of order $10$ and, redundantly, $15$. In summary, a group of order $30$ has proper Hall $\pi$-subgroups of orders $1,2,3,5,6,10$, and $15$. In general, the proper Hall $\pi$-subgroups are the various ways of aggregating the Sylow subgroups.

In general, $\left|G\right|=p^{\alpha}n$ where $\left(p^{\alpha},n\right)=1$. Observe that for $p\in\pi$ or $Q\unlhd G$, via the induction hypothesis, existence and conjugacy are automatically established for Hall $\pi$-subgroups containing $M$ or $Q$ because the Hall subgroups have correlates in the factor groups $G/M$ or $G/Q$. Consider a Hall $\pi$-subgroup $H$ not containing either $M$ or $Q$. The subgroups reference the same set $\pi$ of prime factors so they are aggregates of Sylow subgroups of $G$ determined by these same primes. There is a Sylow subgroup of $H$ conjugate to a Sylow subgroup containing $M$ or $Q$. That is, a conjugate of $H$ is a subgroup containing $M$ or $Q$ so it is conjugate to all Hall $\pi$-subgroups.

On the other hand, suppose $p\not\in\pi$. The lemma implies $G/M^{\prime}$ has a minimal normal subgroup $N/M^{\prime}$ of order prime power $q\neq p$. Let $Q\in\text{Syl}_{q}\left(N\right)$ and $Q$ is a non-normal $q$-subgroup of $G$. By Frattini, $G=NN_{G}\left(Q\right)$ and $Q$ is a subgroup of both $N$ and $N_{G}\left(Q\right)$ so $\left|M^{\prime}\right|\left|Q\right|=\left|N\right|\geq\left|N\cap N_{G}\left(Q\right)\right|=m\left|Q\right|$ for $m\leq\left|M^{\prime}\right|$. Then
\begin{align*}
    p^{\alpha}n
    &=\left|G\right|
    =\frac{\left|N\right|\left|N_{G}\left(Q\right)\right|}{\left|N\cap N_{G}\left(Q\right)\right|}
    =\frac{\left|M^{\prime}\right|\left|Q\right|}{m\left|Q\right|}\left|N_{G}\left(Q\right)\right|
\end{align*}
implies $\left|N_{G}\left(Q\right)\right|=p^{\gamma}n$ for $\gamma <\alpha$ (the inequality is strict as $Q$ is not normal in $G$). This is sufficient, via the induction hypothesis, to show that $G$ has a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of order $n$. Consider any Hall $\pi$-subgroup $H\leq G$ of order $n$ so $H$ has a Sylow $q$-subgroup. Sylow's Theorem implies $Q\leq gHg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$. Then $Q=\left(N\cap gHg^{-1}\right)\unlhd gHg^{-1}$ (see Exercise~3.1.24 and [Holt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2820/derek-holt)) so $gHg^{-1}\leq N_{G}\left(Q\right)$. The Hall $\pi$-subgroups (of appropriate order) of $N_{G}\left(Q\right)$ are conjugate by the induction hypothesis. Thus all Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$ of order $n$ are conjugate.

In fact, the preceding work shows that all Hall $\pi$-subgroups of $G$ for which $p\in\pi$ or $q\in\pi$ exist and are conjugate. A finite induction over the prime factorization of $G$ continues. There is $N^{\prime}$ so $G/N^{\prime}$ has a minimal normal subgroup $K/N^{\prime}$ of order prime power $r\neq p$ and $r\neq q$. Similar reasoning shows that all Hall $\pi$-subgroups with $r\in\pi$ exist and are conjugate and etc. Thus the result.